# Piwik - Exclude from cookie

Tags: cookies, matomo

The new Piwik version 0.6.1 allows you exclude visitors from a cookie.
How must the values look like for that cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the content of the piwik exclude cockie:

```
name: "piwik_ignore"  
value: empty  
domain: "your.piwik.domain"
path: "/"
```